# How do I iterate/select pairs of elements with xpath (1.0)?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml with pairs of a and b elements.and would like to iterate through them and do some work, but can't find the easiest way to do it. I am using C# and want suggestions using .Net. I have tried XmlDocument, XPathNavigator and XmlReader, but got stuck.

I want to find first "a" and then if there is a "b" I want to process that. Then I want to find next "a" and so on.

I think I want something like NextSibling on the level below root, but when I process the elements below a or b I am lost with the pointer/navigator.

```
<root>
   <a>
        <child 1 />
    </a>
    <b>
         <child 2/>
    </b>
    <a>
        <child 1 />
    </a>
    <b>
        <child 2/>
    </b>
.......
</root>
```

Kind Regards
Martin

Comment: Are you talking pure XPath here, or XPath in conjunction with some host language such as XSLT or Java? And which version of XPath?

Comment: I think pure Xpath is enough, but I am using .Net so answers including example in C# will make it easier. Thank you for point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up thinking the other way around, looped all "b" and then lookup up last "a" to get the info I needed

Select all "b"

```
//b
```

and then selected the last "a" preceding current "b" to get the value I needed.

```
(preceding-sibling::a)[last()]
```

Thanks for all inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

As you process each element a, you can test if the first following sibling is element b.

```
<xsl:template match="/root/a">
    ...
    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[1][self::b]">
    ...
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I was looking for. I will try it and come back with feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an up-to-date version of XPath (3.0 or 3.1) you can do this with the `for-each-pair()` function:

```
let $process := function($a, $b) { (: do something :) }
return for-each-pair(//a, //a/following-sibling::*[1][self::b], $process)
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, unfortunately am I stuck with 1.0.

Comment: In future, if you want answers for a specific XPath version (especially an old one), then please make this clear when asking.